# \multicolumn issues

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I try to achieve a table that resembles the one given in this [link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Spanning_in_both_directions_simultaneously).

Here is my code, and the result of running the code:

```
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|}
\cline{2-3}
& \multicolumn{2}{l|}{Inner Rings} &  \multicolumn{4}{l|}{Outer Rings} \\
\cline{2-3} 
& 2.2668  & 1.2866 \\
& 2.5329  & 1.3195 \\
& 2.7484  & 1.3742 \\
& 2.6992  & 1.3403 \\ 
& 2.6338  & 1.3657 \\

\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Average and uncertainty}
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

What I desire to have is three columns, the first column being blank until you reach the row containing "Average and uncertainty";
for the second column, I would like "Outer Rings" to be above 2.2668, 2.5329, etc.;
and for the third column, I would like "Inner Rings" to be above 1.2866, 1.3195, etc.

How might I achieve this? I have tried many things.

Comment: The first argument of multicolumn is the quantity of columns it spans. So the sum of all those columns in one row must be the same as stated behind `\egin{tabular}{<quantity>}`. Furthermore, you specified 3 columns, but i just see two.

Comment: You get at least one compilation error with that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or rather something like this, using `siuntix` and `booktabs`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{
    S[table-format=1.4]
    S[table-format=1.4]
}
    \toprule
    {Outer Rings} &{Inner Rings} \\
    \midrule
    2.2668  & 1.2866 \\
    2.5329  & 1.3195 \\
    2.7484  & 1.3742 \\
    2.6992  & 1.3403 \\ 
    2.6338  & 1.3657 \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-2}
    2.576+-.19 & 1.337+-0.04 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

But it's really hard to tell what you really want. I didn't go for all those vertical lines, since they distract the reader. Think of the tables in all the articles you are reading. More information on how to typeset nice tables can be found in the documentation of [booktabs](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs).

Comment: With `S[table-format=1.4]` the alignment would be better.

Comment: @egreg You are right. and since i don't like uncertainty to take up su much space, i left that part out.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|}
\cline{2-3}
& Inner Rings &  Outer Rings \\
\cline{2-3}
& 2.2668  & 1.2866 \\
& 2.5329  & 1.3195 \\
& 2.7484  & 1.3742 \\
& 2.6992  & 1.3403 \\
& 2.6338  & 1.3657 \\

Average and uncertainty &&
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The OP probably would want the last lines to be `\cline{1-3} \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Average and uncertainty}`, considering the examples he linked to.

Comment: So, it was unnecessary to use \multicolumn  ?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `multicolumn` here, when you are not writing over multiple columns? You can can remove all the `multicolumn` related code (except for the one at the end, which introduces the `|` at the beginning of the line) and the table looks like you described in your text.

This would result in the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|}
\cline{2-3}
&{Inner Rings} &  {Outer Rings} \\
\cline{2-3}
& 2.2668  & 1.2866 \\
& 2.5329  & 1.3195 \\
& 2.7484  & 1.3742 \\
& 2.6992  & 1.3403 \\
& 2.6338  & 1.3657 \\
\cline{1-3}
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Average and uncertainty}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, there was one \cline{1-3} too much. I edited my code.